# Access contentWindow from dynamically created iFrame

Tags: lightning-aura-components, iframe

I dynamically create an `iframe` as this:

```
$A.createComponent(
  'aura:HTML',
  {
    tag: 'iframe',
    HTMLAttributes: {
      'aura:id':  'iframe',
      id:         'iframe',
      style:      component.get('v.style'),
      src:        context.uriCRM,
      width:      component.get('v.width'),
      height:     component.get('v.height'),
      scrolling:  component.get('v.scrolling'),
      frameborder:component.get('v.frameBorder'),
      sandbox:    component.get('v.sandbox'),
      onload:     component.getReference('c.iframeLoaded'),
      error:      component.getReference('c.iframeNotLoaded')
    }
  },
  (iframe, status, errorMessage) => {
    if (status === 'SUCCESS') {
      console.log(iframe.getElement()); // null
      console.log(iframe.contentWindow); // null
      component.set('v.iframe', iframe);
    } else {
      this.setError(component, errorMessage);
    }
  }
```

I would like to access `contentWindow`. How can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Originally, I said:

> You'll never be able to get access to the elements inside aura:html
>   because it is in a different namespace to your component - so Locker
>   Service will prevent you from getting any elements inside it.

I think this is wrong and the problem is that you're trying to get the element before the new component has actually rendered. A bit like the common mistake of trying to do this on `init` instead of on `render`. Your component does own the iframe component, so it should be allowed to read it, it's just not rendered yet.

I think you'd be better off just injecting it into the DOM, if you really have to do this i.e. have some `<div aura:id="iframeHolder">` in the markup to show where the iframe needs to go, then something like this:

```
var theFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
component.find(iframeHolder).getElement().appendChild(theFrame);
```

Although, I'd think very hard about whether I could achieve this using `<aura:if>` and/or expressions in the markup instead of dynamically creating components because that would be a lot easier

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The goal was to `noop` the `console.log` function from the iFrame (`contentWindow.console.log = function() {}`).

Comment: Actually, I got it wrong and I writing the right answer... hang tight for a moment!

Comment: @SimonPlacentino finished editing, you might still have an uphill battle if you want to override console.log of the parent window, though

Comment: Thank you for you answer (and edit). Then, how to handle the action to perform from the `render` function but ONLY for first render of the `iframe` ?

Comment: If your c.iframeLoaded method is getting called, you could do it there. I've done something like that (but I didn't dynamically create the iframe)

Comment: I tried but `component.getContent().contentWindow` is not referencing the good component. `component.find('apex')` is `undefined`.